# How to read Angular JS code when it is too vague

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have copied&pasted the angularJS source code into an online beautifier and then started reading it. What I encountered was a set of function with single or double letters as their name and with many more codes inside which seems to be vague (of course, FOR ME).

For instance, the first block of AngularJS starts witht this function:

```
function t(b) {
    return function () {
        var a = arguments[0],
            c, a = "[" + (b ? b + ":" : "") + a + "] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/" + (b ? b + "/" : "") + a;
        for (c = 1; c < arguments.length; c++) a = a + (1 == c ? "?" : "&") + "p" + (c - 1) + "=" + encodeURIComponent("function" == typeof arguments[c] ? arguments[c].toString().replace(/ \{[\s\S]*$/, "") : "undefined" == typeof arguments[c] ? "undefined" : "string" != typeof arguments[c] ? JSON.stringify(arguments[c]) : arguments[c]);
        return Error(a)
    }
}
```

I really don't grasp much from this script, but that's for sure my lack of adequate knowledge. Now, I have this question:

Why namings are like this? Is it their choice or it has some technical reasons behind? And how should this code be dissected and analyzed as a code-reading process?

Comment: The code has gone through a compiler which replaces variable names (and others such as function names) with shorter words/letters to make the code as small as possible.

Comment: try including the un-minified script - might be easier to read:)

Comment: OWWWWW!!!! I really liked that..I didn't noticed that, the you mean this is a systematized naming produced primarily by a machine-system. Thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

The code you are looking at is minified version (processed by some minifier example YUI-minifier), which is done to make the code size small. Try seeing the unminified version of  the script and things will be clear to you.